# How to Display Dicussion on Facebook Page on my custom PHP page

Tags: php

i Want to display facebook page discussions on my custom PHP page is it possible.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Facebook's Social Plugins:

http://developers.facebook.com/plugins

The ones that you most probably want are **Like Box** (displays updates from your Facebook Page) and **Live Stream** (real-time discussion on events by users on your site's page).